# Unable to locate element by xpath using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am creating a Selenium bot in Python. The driver is supposed to open instagram.com and fill in the login form using the users credentials as an input. There is an error:

```
# FIRST I OPEN INSTAGRAM LIKE THIS
self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

# THEN A POP-UP APPEARS, AND I CLOSE IT BY CLICKING IN THE ACCEPT BUTTON,
# IT SEEMS LIKE IT IS NOT AN IFRAME SO NO FRAME SWITCHES ARE NEEDED
cooki = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]')
cooki.click() 
 
# NOW I TRY TO FIND THE USERNAME FORM TO WRITE IN AN INPUT
usbar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]')    # ERROR HERE
usbar.send_keys(input('Username: '))
```

The error says:

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]"}

It cannot find the Username form to write in it. I believe there are no iframes in the way, I don't know if there is any other issue preventing the driver to find it. I am fairly new so I can't upload an image of the html of the page yet, that's why I include the line that opens the page. Can anyone come up with a foolproof solution?

Comment: Have you checked the page source which your program ends up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see there are two problems.

You are trying to call `send_keys()` on a `div` element.  What you are likely looking for is the `input` element instead, which is nested inside of that `div` element.

This can be obtained by changing your XPATH slightly:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="username"]')
element.send_keys('...')
```

Another possible issue is that elements aren't always loaded immediately - you sometimes have to wait for the element to appear in the HTML before finding it.  This can be achieved using [`Webdriver.Wait()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Wait for the element to appear in the HTML for a maximum of 10 seconds
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username"))
)

# Send input to the element
element.send_keys('...')
```

Comment: I changed the XPath to the input as you said. To be honest that's what I did in the first place, but the error arised so I tried finding another path, and that's what I showed. I'm using the WebDriverWait() as you said, but now it says (NameError: name 'By' is not defined). Also, I changed By.NAME with By.XPATH, and used the path to the input. I guess with that, the find_element_by_xpath I wrote in the original is not needed right?

Comment: @VektorElektor you get `NameError` because you have to import `By` from `selenium.webdriver.common.by` (see the top of the second code snippet).  And yes, the `find_element_by_xpath` function is not needed if you use `WebDriverWait` because that will return the element once the element appears in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup the full xpatch using inspect in Google Chrome.
Your code then becomes:

```
usbar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
```

[image]

Comment: That is how im looking for the Xpaths, and I have already tried 'Copy full XPath' instead of 'Copy XPath', but to no avail.